# Angular promise fail

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I wrote some code for promise understanding:

```
function test1() {
    return $http.get("google.com").then(function (data) {
        console.log("OK1");
    }, function (data) {
        console.log("ERROR1");
    });
}

$scope.test = function() {
    test1().then(function (data) {
        console.log("OK2");
    }, function (data) {
        console.log("ERROR2");
    });        
}
```

And when I try execute this I get `ERROR 1 OK2` but I expect `ERROR1 ERROR2`.

How understand that?

Full example: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/14804/

Comment: Why not just use `.success` and `.error` instead?

Comment: Would you also have expected to get the `data` from the request in the second handler? No, promises returned by `then` resolve with the results from the callback(s).

Comment: @ryanyuyu This is very simplified example. In my real app `test1` and `test` function located in different unit.